Graph API Excel Update tablerow
I am trying to update a row in a table using GraphApi. According to the documentation, the code should look like this:
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Serialization;

var requestBody = new WorkbookTableRow
{
    Index = 99,
    Values = new UntypedString("values-value"),
};

var result = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Items["{driveItem-id}"].Workbook.Tables["{workbookTable-id}"].Rows["{workbookTableRow-id}"].PatchAsync(requestBody);

I get the error message “The Api you are trying to use could not be found.”
The http call according to the documentation looks like this and does not work either. I get the same error message in Graph Explorer:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/tables/{id|name}/rows/{index}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "index": 99,
  "values": "values-value"
}

If I call the following in Graph Explorer, it works:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/drive-id/items/driveItem-id/workbook/tables/table-id/rows/**itemAt(index=0)**
{
  "values": "values-value"
}

What does the C# code look like?

The correct code should look like this
var requestBody = new WorkbookTableRow
{
    Values = new UntypedArray(new List<UntypedNode>
    {
        new UntypedArray(new List<UntypedNode>
        {
            new UntypedString("column1-value"),
            new UntypedString("column2-value")
        })
    })
};

var result = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Items["{driveItem-id}"].Workbook.Tables["{workbookTable-id}"].Rows.ItemAtWithIndex(99).PatchAsync(requestBody);

Unfortunately, the SDK doesn't generate PatchAsync method for the endpoint
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/drive-id/items/driveItem-id/workbook/tables/table-id/rows/itemAt(index=0)
{
  "values": "values-value"
}

Please create a new issue for that in the Graph .NET SDK repo:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues
Currently, there is no workaround for this

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/2699
